# WaveIn API fails on mobile platform during work

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-mobile

I am capturing real time audio on a Pocket PC device in C#/.NET, using a
WaveIn P/Invoke example. I am recycling the `WAVEHDR`
buffers by doing a `waveInUnprepareHeader`, `waveInPrepareHeader`,
`waveInAddBuffer` sequence. This all works fine for about 2 - 60 seconds, but after, `waveInUnprepareHeader`, `waveInPrepareHeader`, and `waveInAddBuffer` (all of them) returns an `INVALPARAM` error and audio input ceases.

How can i avoid this bug and solve the problem?

Comment: This is hard to visualize. Is there code you can show?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess (based on no code) is that your device is running out of internal RAM for recording this audio.